# package sistyle and SIunits conflict, \micro already defined

Tags: errors, siunitx, siunits

I've got an error on my latex file when i use both package at the same time.
I haven't this error when i dont use one of the 2 package

```
 LaTeX Error: Command \micro already defined.

 Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

 See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
 Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
  ...                                              

 l.609 \begin{document}

 Your command was ignored.
 Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
 or  <return>  to continue without it.
```

But if I don't use the SIUnits package I got errors on these commands:

```
\ampere
\ohm
\degreecelsius
\volt
\mega \ohm
\milli \ohm
\kelvin
```

And when I dont use sistyle package I got errors on these commands

```
\num*
\sqrt \num*
```

Here is the small example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{chemist}      
\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC}
\usepackage[european]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{sistyle}
\usepackage{SIunits}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{color}

%
%

\begin{document}

THIS IS A TEST
\end{document}
```

Can you help me

Thank you

Jules

Comment: we cant help you if we not see complete but small document which gives your error. try to use `siunitx` package. `SIunits` is considered obsolete.

Comment: If I use siunitx I can't use sistyle so i removed sistyle but i've got 110 errors With function like degreecelsius and with num* and other functions

Comment: packages unfortunately are not compatible. however by help of editor you can easily change `SIunits` names to `siunitx` ones.

Comment: ok but then for example I just tried this and I got error !!!!!!! \num{5e{-4}} \si{\volt}

Comment: Don't use both packages. They are incompatible. Use only siunitx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change order how you load packages in preamble to:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{chemist}
%\usepackage{etex} it is some years default
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC}
\usepackage[european]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{SIunits}
\usepackage{sistyle}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

THIS IS A TEST
\end{document}
```

however, you should consider to use `siunitx` and changes used units names accordingly (by help of editor `find-replace` function) and drop `SIunits`
and `sistyle`.

Comment: Ok im trying to do this thx